Why doesn't execute code under if not prefix statement in discord.py?
@commands.command(aliases=['префикс'])
async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix):
    if not prefix:
        await ctx.send(f"Current prefix - {self.client.command_prefix}")
    else:
        self.client.command_prefix = prefix
        await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to {prefix}")

When the user types just !prefix (without any text after) the bot does nothing, but if the user provides some text after the command (!prefix ?) bot sends some text and successfully changes the prefix!
Why isn't the "if not prefix" block executed?

In your code, the prefix argument is required and not optional. So using !prefix with nothing after would throw an error that an argument was missing.
To fix this, we can make it optional by setting a default value.
@commands.command(aliases=['префикс'])
async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix=None):
    if prefix is None: #  More accurate check
        await ctx.send(f"Current prefix - {self.client.command_prefix}")
    else:
        self.client.command_prefix = prefix
        await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to {prefix}")

This way, when prefix isn't given (ran !prefix), the prefix will be set to None and still go through the code.
Another way is by using typing.Optional along with type annotation.
from typing import Optional


@commands.command(aliases=['префикс'])
async def prefix(self, ctx: commands.Context, prefix: Optional[str]):
     ...

This effectively does the same thing.
